# How to install IoT version of Windows on Raspberry PI 4?

Tags: windows-iot, windows

I wanted to see if there is a way to install Windows 10 IoT edition on Raspberry Pi 4 or not? I already knew that Windows 10 IoT edition can be installed on Raspberry Pi 3, but recently I noticed that it is not possible to install it on the newer Raspberry Pi.
If there is no way to install it, can you suggest suitable and powerful hardware like Raspberry Pi 4 to install the Windows 10 IoT edition on it?
Since I need an embedded Windows operating system, what do you think about the newly introduced Windows 10 IoT Enterprise? Can they be installed on Raspberry Pi 4?

Comment: MS seems to have abandoned Win10-IOT for the Pi a long time ago. Last version was a (beta) for the Pi3B+ several years ago.

Comment: Thanks, I installed it for my new raspberry pi 3.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not support Win10-IOT on the Raspberry Pi 4. Some reports suggest that you can make it work, although not all the hardware seems to work (e.g. no WiFi etc.) Support for the Pi 3 also seems abandoned.

Microsoft seems to prefer that you use a DragonBoard, Up2 Board or NXP device, but I am not a Windows IOT expert, and the Pi-stack exchange site is not a place to get these kind of hardware recommendations.

Comment: Microsoft dropped support for Win10IoT in February 2018 when the 3B+ launched. It will only run on a 2B (version 1, not the later 2B with the newer CPU) or 3B.

Comment: @Dougie Thanks, windows 10 IoT core run almost fine on my new raspberry pi 3.